# Microsoft.ACE>OLEDB12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, ms-access-2013

When I try to connect my programme with the database, a message says

`The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.`

I already installed "**Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable**"

Have any idea?

Comment: You must execute your application under the same architecture of your driver, that's it, as 64 or 32 bit. For example, if you run your app as 32bit but your oledb provider is 64bit, you will get that error. You can change that in your project properties, Build tab.

Comment: Thnkz Ali, But the thing is that I am using same architecture. Can you tell..  This issue related to OS or Office package.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

- First, ensure that you have installed the correct version of the
  database engine; you can download the 32bit/64bit version from here:
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
- The installed driver can only be used within an application running under
  the same architecture, therefore, try building your application to
  run as 32bit or 64bit; you can do this from your project properties,
  Build tab, please try the following two combinations and see which
  one works:

[image: x86]

---

[image: x64]

Also, you can use the `System.Environment.Is64BitProcess` property to tell if your process in running as 64-bit.

Hope this helps.